# SQL Server - "false" IF statement skipped, but still takes usual time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Simplified example of my situation: I have a script like so:

```
DECLARE @var1 int = 1
DECLARE @var2 int = 2

IF (@var1 = 1)
   BEGIN
      -- Small SELECT statement that uses @var2
      -- Usually takes less than a second to complete
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
      -- Large SELECT statement that uses @var2
      -- Usually takes roughly 8 seconds to complete
   END
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is:

If `@var1` = `1`, and `@var2` = (anything), the script runs in less than a second, as expected.

But if I change the value of `@var2` while keeping `@var1` = 1, the runtime suddenly jumps to 8 seconds, even though the `ELSE` clause isn't entered.

For example, here are the results if I sequentially do the following:

```
1) @var1 = 1, @var2 = 2 -- Less than a second
2) @var1 = 1, @var2 = 3 -- 8 seconds even though ELSE clause isn't entered?
3) @var1 = 1, @var2 = 3 -- Less than a second
```

It almost seems as if the `SELECT` statement in the `ELSE` clause is being re-evaluated, even though it isn't actually returning anything. Is this expected behavior in SQL Server?

(Note that if I comment out the `ELSE` clause entirely, the script always completes in less than a second.)

I attempted to troubleshoot the problem like this:

```
DECLARE @var1 int = 1
DECLARE @var2 int = 2

DECLARE @time1 datetime = GETDATE()

IF (@var1 = 1)
   BEGIN
      -- Small SELECT statement that uses @var2
      -- Usually takes less than a second to complete
   END

DECLARE @time2 datetime = GETDATE()

IF (@var1 <> 1)
   BEGIN
      -- Large SELECT statement that uses @var2
      -- Usually takes roughly 8 seconds to complete
   END

DECLARE @time3 datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT @time1 [Time 1], @time2 [Time 2], @time3 [Time 3]
```

As expected, `@time2` equals `@time3`, because the `ELSE` clause is never entered, but the runtime of the script is still 8 seconds? Why?

See screenshot of results below.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a compilation issue.  Try with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to see if that fixes the performance issue.

Comment: You will probably need to look at the different execution plans and figure out what is causing the degraded performance.

Comment: Could tell more about the code which is skipped?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, that helped with this problem.